# Join multiple rows give one distinct row

Tags: sql

My SQL statement returns the following

```
SQLID  Col1  Col2  Col3
14945  NULL  NULL  sdf
14945  NULL  xyz   NULL
14945  abc   NULL  NULL
```

where as I would like it to return

```
SQLID   Col1 Col2   Col3
14945   abc  xyz    sdf
```

Please help.

The schema is such that I have a table which contains `SQLID`'s. And a second table which contains `SQLID`'s as the FK to first table and the col1, col2 and col3. Currently I am just doing a join on `SQLId`

```
Select 
    t1.SQLID, t2.Col1, t2.col2, t2.col3
from
    Table1 t1 
join
    table2 t2 on t1.SQLId = t2.SQLid
```

Comment: And what should happen if you have multiple values in a given column for a SQLID?  I assume `SELECT MAX` for each column should work, but want to make sure.

Comment: Your sample data is just too limited. As LittleBobbyTables said, what happens if there are other values for the same ID on those columns?

Comment: No every column will have only one value for each sqlid

Comment: The Schema is such that i have a table which contains SQLIDs. And a second table which contains SQLIDs as the FK to first table and the col1, col2 and col3. Currently I am just doing a join on SQLId

Comment: @sarsha why did you undo the edits?, you un-formated your post again. And replaced *following* with *follwing*

Comment: Looks like its time to use PIVOTS!

Comment: If col1,col2,col3 are `DATETIME` data type as you say (`as per your comment to my answer`) please change sample data to 'DATETIME` as well. Otherwise people get confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pivot Multiple Rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846148/pivot-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** if Col1, Col2, Col3 are `DATETIME` datatype (as per following comment)
You can use;

```
SELECT SQLID, MAX(ISNULL(Col1,0)) AS Col1,
        MAX(ISNULL(Col2,0)) AS Col2, MAX(ISNULL(Col3,0)) AS Col3
FROM YourTable
GROUP By SQLID
```

Comment: Probably want to add the `GROUP BY` to your second example just for consistency.

Comment: Col1, col2 and Col3 are not actually integers. I am using this just to represent the format. They are actuallty DateTime

Comment: @sarsha, second query will still work for datetime. if you set `isnull(col1,0)` it will set `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` for null values